# SnipMate error on autocomplete

Tags: vim, snipmate

Minimal working example, of a JavaScript file:

```
class ClassName{
```

Upon pressing the tab key in insert mode, with the cursor right after the curly bracket, the following error is shown:

```
Error detected while processing function snipMate#TriggerSnippet[35]..snipMate#GetSnippetsForWordBelowCursor[31]..funcref#Call[61]..snipMate#GetSnippets[4]..funcref#Call[61]..snipMate#DefaultPool[13]..<SNR>117_Glob:
line    5:
E220: Missing }.
```

Other than SnipMate, I've installed the required dependency plugins:  [vim-addon-mw-utils](https://github.com/marcweber/vim-addon-mw-utils) and [tlib](https://github.com/tomtom/tlib_vim). I've also installed [vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets).

I'm running the console version of Vim 8 (32bit) on Windows 10.

What could be causing the error?

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: @romainl I already [did](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/issues/264). :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [issue that you've entered](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/issues/264), this was a bug in the plugin that has been fixed by now. Please don't use [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for plugin issues, especially if the project is active and well maintained.